# How can I get the first and last item of every item of list

Tags: python

I have a list of names of persons and I want to extract the title and the last name. I have written the following code:

```
people = ['Dr. Christopher Brooks', 'Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson', 'Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran', 'Dr. Daniel Romero']

def split_title_and_name(person):
    for i in person:
        title = [i.split(' ')[0] for i in person]
        lname = [i.split(' ')[-1] for i in person]
    return (title + lname)
```

The output I'm getting is :

```
['Dr.',
 'Dr.',
 'Dr.',
 'Dr.',
 'Brooks',
 'Collins-Thompson',
 'Vydiswaran',
 'Romero']
```

The result which I want is like this:

```
['Dr.Brooks' , 'Dr.Collins-Thompson' ...]
```

Comment: the title of your question is pretty  confusing, please clarify

Comment: What is the expected output for `Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran`? What rule should be used to determine what is the last name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

title contains a list of all first names
lname contains a los of all the last names
Seems like you need a zip operation

```py
print("Zip:")
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two separate lists, just do it all at once:

```
names = [i.split(' ')[0] + i.split(' ')[-1] for i in people]
```

The way you're doing it, you're trying to add two lists together - what you want is to add the two strings together as you're making the list. You can do this all in one line, as above - the outer `for` loop isn't even necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to split in a comprehension and then pull out the first and last in another one:

```
people = ['Dr. Christopher Brooks', 'Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson', 'Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran', 'Dr. Daniel Romero']

[n[0]+n[-1] for n in [p.split(' ') for p in people]]

>>> ['Dr.Brooks', 'Dr.Collins-Thompson', 'Dr.Vydiswaran', 'Dr.Romero']
```

You could also split with a regex, although this is probably overkill for this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("\s.+\s")
[''.join(regex.split(s)) for s in people]

>>> ['Dr.Brooks', 'Dr.Collins-Thompson', 'Dr.Vydiswaran', 'Dr.Romero']
```